# Curl open PHP Script to create PDF file does not work

Tags: php, pdf, curl

I have a programm, which creates a PDF file from created documents if you click on a url. The url looks like this:
http://localhost:8080/interface/rme.php?class=Auftrag&constructor=10&method=getGRLBMPDF&parameters=%27false%27,%27%27,%2710%27&bps=_Brief;templateType:PDF

The value "10" in "...constructor=10..." is equal to the document number. So if I would like to get a PDF from document with the number 9, I just have to replace the number and the url does work.

The problem is: This only works in browsers, and I would like to get the PDF file via PHP script.

I tried to open the url with curl and multiple options, but nothing works.

The programm has a temp directory, which is empty. If I open the link the PDF file is generated inside this temp directory, and the URL redirects me to the new generated PDF file inside the temp directory. I think this is where the problem belongs.

If I open the url with curl, wget or similar, the PDF does not get generated. The Page I receive with curl contains just "-1".

Has someone an idea why this does not work? I have curl set to follow redirects and its allowed by my ini file too.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: access via the url if its local-hosted is probably not the best approach.

Comment: Hi Dagon, thanks for reply. Yes I know, if you have an other solution, please tell me. Can it work with "include"? I was not able to get it to work with include...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue:

First I have defined all Get-Variables:

```
$_GET['class'] = "Auftrag";
$_GET['constructor'] = $Auftrag_ID;
$_GET['method'] = "getGRLBMPDF";
$_GET['parameters'] = "'false','','".$Auftrag_ID."'";
$_GET['bps'] = "_Brief;templateType:PDF";
```

Then I changed the directory to the PHP file in my url:

```
$dir=$programpath."interface";
chdir($dir);
```

After that I included the PHP file with require:

```
ob_start();
require("rme.php");
$data = ob_get_clean();
```

Now everything is working fine. Thanks to anyone who has read my problem.

Regards,
Vidarrus